# Call db2 stored procedure with array as input parameter

Tags: sql, db2

I created a custom SQL type to represent a VARCHAR array because I want to pass an array of VARCHAR as an input parameter to my stored proc. I'm currently get an error when I try call my stored proc

Here's my custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE PARTNUMBERARRAY  AS VARCHAR(21) ARRAY[100];
```

Here's my stored procedure signature:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE partNumbersFetch(
    IN partNumbers PARTNUMBERARRAY
)
```

I tried to call the stored procedure like this:

`CALL partNumbersFetch(array['A6541404301','A112300423']);`

but I get this error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "ARRAY[" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "<name>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.25.25
```

How can I call this stored procedure successfully?

Comment: Not sure but I think you need to use a variable. https://dbfiddle.uk/TSlONEJi